# How to upload images to database MYSQL in ionic 4?

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I hope you can help me I want to insert the name of the image in my database as well as upload the file to my server PHP but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you aware of things that we always write the images in folder and
>   always keep the unique name of the images in database.This is not the
>   good way to store images in Database. So convert the images in Base64
>   formate send it to server end(PHP).And see the code to upload images
>   in folder and save unique name in database.

```
//Call this function after getting base64 by post

$imageBase64=$_POST['image_converted_base64'];//get base64 of image from client end

 $unique_name =uploadSingleImage($imageBase64);//function call

//function to upload image and get an unique name to store in db

    function uploadSingleImage($base64) {

        $uniname = uniqid() . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".jpg";
        $new_image_url = "../../image/" . $uniname;
        $base64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $base64;
        $base64 = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $base64));
        file_put_contents($new_image_url, $base64);
        return $uniname;
    }

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table1`(image_name) VALUES('$unique_name')";
$conn->query($sql);
```